# Yii2, отправка формы с помощью pjax

Tags: php, yii2, pjax

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь отправить форму с помощью pjax как написано здесь http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/772/pjax-on-activeform-and-gridview-yii2/

```
    <?php Pjax::begin(['enablePushState' => false,'timeout' => 5000,'id' => 'pjax_form']); ?>
    <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data-pjax' => true],['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],'id' => 'dynamic-form']) ?>
/*список полей*/
  <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
        <?php Pjax::end(); ?>
```

получаю ошибку если указываю атрибут

> ['data-pjax' => true] - Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ActiveForm::0

А если не пишу, то страница перезагружается при нажатии на кнопку. Может кто- то сталкивался, как можно исправить это?

Answer (score 2):

Просто атрибут указан не в том месте.

Правильно будет так:

```
$form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['data-pjax' => true,'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],'id' => 'dynamic-form']);
```